# How do I print this in 2 decimal places?

Tags: python, decimal

distance = 10

total = 0

for days in range (1,15):

```
total += distance
print ("Day", days, "travelled",  distance, "miles", "total" , total )
distance *= .8
```

Comment: Did you really bother searching for this before posting? There are dozens of questions about printing a certain number of decimal places.

Comment: @Barmar that's the wrong dupe, that's with the `Decimal` type, not generic floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the ``round" function

```
distance = 10
total = 0

for days in range (1,15):
    total += distance
    print ("Day", days, "travelled",  round(distance, 2), "miles", "total" , round(total, 2) )
    distance *= .8
```